# please help me add columns in ssis

Tags: ssis

Hi friends i have small doubt in ssis please tell me how to solve this issuse in sql server.

table:patient

```
pn | cpt1 |cpt2 | cpt3| modi12  | modi13  | modi22 | modi33 | mod31|modi11
1  |100   |200  |300  |  a      |         |g       |  k     | v    |q
2  |101   |400  |450  |  h      |   b     |        |        | m    |
```

Here modi13 means modfiere1  with cpt3
modi12 means modifier1  with cpt2
modi22 means modifier2 with cpt2
modi33 means modifier3 with cpt3
modi31 means modifier3 with cpt1
modi11 means modifier1 with cpt1
modi13 means modifier1 with cpt3

based on this condition i need output like this

```
       pn  |   cpt   |    modifier1    |   modifier2  | modifier3
       1   |   100   |     q           |             |v
       2   |   101   |                 |             |m
       1   |   200   |     a           |  g          |
       2   |   400   |     h           |             |
       1   |   300   |                 |             |k
       2   |   450   |     b           |             |
```

i tried cpt1,cpt2,cpt3 information stored in cpt useing unpivot.but here problem is how i displaay corresponding modfier1 and modifier2 and modifier3 values information.
select cpt from
 ( select pn,cpt1,cpt2,cpt3 from patient)main
 unpivot
  ( cpt  for cptvalues in (cpt1,cpt2,cpt3))sub that time i get only upto pn corresponding cpt values.

please tell me .  how to solve this issue in  ssis .

Comment: A search on "SSIS unpivot" returns much information. Why don't you try some examples and post any issues you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSIS, you could use a multicast, map for example

pn | cpt1 |modi11

to a result set, do this for all of them,

pn | cpt2 |modi21  etc.

then use a union task and put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    int pn = Row.pn;
    int cpt1 = Row.cpt1;
    int cpt2 = Row.cpt2;
    int cpt3 = Row.cpt3;
    string modi11 = Row.modi11;
    string modi12 = Row.modi12;
    string modi13 = Row.modi13;
    string modi22 = Row.modi22;
    string modi31 = Row.modi31;
    string modi33 = Row.modi33;

    ///modi11 means modifier1 with cpt1 
    ///modi31 means modifier3 with cpt1
    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
    Output0Buffer.pn = pn;

    Output0Buffer.cpt = cpt1;
    Output0Buffer.modifier1 = modi11;
    //Output0Buffer.modifier2 = modi21;
    Output0Buffer.modifier3 = modi31;

    ///modi12 means modifier1 with cpt2 
    ///modi22 means modifier2 with cpt2 
    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
    Output0Buffer.pn = pn;

    Output0Buffer.cpt = cpt2;
    Output0Buffer.modifier1 = modi12;
    Output0Buffer.modifier2 = modi22;
    //Output0Buffer.modifier3 = modi32;

    ///modi13 means modfiere1 with cpt3 
    ///modi33 means modifier3 with cpt3
    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
    Output0Buffer.pn = pn;

    Output0Buffer.cpt = cpt1;
    Output0Buffer.modifier1 = modi13;
    //Output0Buffer.modifier2 = modi23;
    Output0Buffer.modifier3 = modi33;
}
```

Note: Add code to handle null (intentionally left for you ;-)